# android system can use swap partition in SD card?

Tags: android

I want to do app2sd for install soft&app to sd.somebody said can split a swap in sd and run app is faster.
I don't think so that .I don't know linux core in android  can use swap in sd??

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Consider superuser.com or android.stackexchange.com for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Swap increase your RAM capacity (in laic speech). It corresponds to swap on linux or pagefile(? i'm czech guy so not sure this term is correct) on windows system. So it makes your apps not crash down by RAM deficit (that means your RAM is used up for other tasks and have no space for new task, even after killing unused tasks) by storing part of your RAM on SD card (or elsewhere, again in laic speech). It could make your apps run faster but that's just side-effect imho. but your large spreadsheets or games or other stuff never crash down due low RAM resources anymore;)

For app2sd you don't need swap nor split your card.. just root your android and it should work fine with any card of any capacity (faster=better; follow some class-related discussion). By rootin you may lose your guarantee (again not sure about the term:)) but there is an app (just google it;)) for doing it without flashing or stuff and the rootin process is reversible by using that app..;)

With android 2.2 and newer, you don't even need to root it - it's already allowed in the system.